# JS function that logs properties of nested objects, where properties are passed as parameters

Tags: javascript, function, object, ecmascript-6

I have the following object:

```
let a = {
    aa: {
        aaa: 1
    },
    ab: {
        aba: {
            abaa: 2
        }
    }
}
```

I want to write a function to which you can pass an object plus an arbitrary number of strings denoting nested properties in that object, and have the function output the corresponding value. For example:

```
func(a, 'aa', 'aaa') // 1
func(a, 'ab', 'aba', 'abaa') // 2
```

I'm able to do this if the number of parameters is fixed, like this:

```
function func() {
    console.log(arguments[0][arguments[1]][arguments[2]])
}
```

Does anyone know how I can write `func()` so that it will accept an arbitrary number of arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over `arguments` based on its length:

```
function func() {
    var obj = arguments[0];
    for(var i = 1; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
        obj = obj[arguments[i]];
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Or if you're using modern JavaScript, you can do it this way instead:

```
function func(obj, ...keys) {
    keys.forEach(key => obj = obj[key]);
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `reduce` with `arguments`:

```js
let a = {
  aa: {
    aaa: 1
  },
  ab: {
    aba: {
      abaa: 2
    }
  }
}

function func() {
  console.log([...arguments].reduce((a, c) => a[c]));
}

func(a, 'aa', 'aaa');
func(a, 'ab', 'aba', 'abaa');
```

If you don't like using `arguments`, use rest and spreading `...`:

```js
let a = {
  aa: {
    aaa: 1
  },
  ab: {
    aba: {
      abaa: 2
    }
  }
}

function func(...args) {
  console.log(args.reduce((a, c) => a[c]));
}

func(a, 'aa', 'aaa');
func(a, 'ab', 'aba', 'abaa');
```

Comment: Thanks! This does work, I appreciate it. I'm going to give the green check to Joseph Sible's answer because it came in first, but your solution's what I was looking for as well.

Comment: I actually like this answer better than my own.

Comment: Thanks @JosephSible, always nice to know people like my answers.

Answer (score 1):

It's convenient to deal arbitrary number of arguments with es6 [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```
function logNestProperties(obj, ...args) {
    let value = args.reduce((acc, cur) => acc[cur], obj);
    console.log(value || 'illegal properties');
}
```